# GridView throwing null on child id

Tags: android, gridview

My gridview is throwing null on asking for child id, i have looked to similar question but my view is not scroll able so no child view is reused . I want that after gridview appears on screen few random child change their colour . I have kept the code in on start as on start does thing after the screen appears on phone . I have to ask whether this part code should be kept in on start or on resume or on create method and why i am getting null pointer error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        id1 = Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("number"));
        Log.i("id1bnrgbngbnb", id1.toString());
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images);
        height = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        width = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        heightofactivity = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
        gridview.setNumColumns(id1);
        gridview.setColumnWidth(widthofactivity / id1);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }


    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int x = numberofboxestoselect(id1);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            numbers.add(selectrandomnumers(id1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("numbers", numbers.toString());

            View v = gridview.getChildAt(numbers.get(i));

            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

    }

    private int numberofboxestoselect(Integer id1) {
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = id1 * id1 - 1;
        return Min + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    }
```

**Log cat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.utkarsh.finomena.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:74)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1260)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6276)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: I guess I know the problem, But still I would like to see your logcat

Answer (score 0):

int widthofactivity was not there so it took the default 0 ; becuase of which gridview object got crested but no gridview and there no child. and i have attached viewtreeobserver with gridview then wrote the code in global layout method